# I need a example of digital instrument for measurement capacivity with icl7106

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, circuit-design, oscilloscope, datasheet

Hi guys i have to make digital instrument for measurement capacivity with icl7106. Can you give me some examples of digital instruments with this icl7106 i cant find on internet full circuit. And yes some advice will be helpful.

Comment: Something as this icl7106 or icl7107 ... https://www.petervis.com/meters/ICL7106%20and%20ICL7107%20Digital%20Meter/ICL7106%20and%20ICL7107%20Digital%20Meter%20Schematic.html

Comment: **capacivity** isn't a real word. Do you mean capacity, capacitance or capacitively? It makes a difference to the meaning of your question.

Answer (score 0):

ICL7106 was an off-shoot of a chip used by Fluke in their [8010a, 8020 digital multimeters](https://www.qsl.net/n9zia/test/Fluke-8010A_Instruction_Manual.pdf). Pin-out is similar.
The IC7106 substitutes an RC timing clock for Fluke's crystal oscillator.

I'm unsure if it is capable of "measurement capacivity".